# Capture system audio on an android rooted phone

Tags: android, audio, stream, system, root

I want to stream all the audio of my android phone to PC. I know it's impossible to capture the system audio with an unrooted phone. Is it possible with a rooted phone? Does anyone have some idea how I may achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: This is pretty close to your question of June 26: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199867/turn-pc-to-a-dock-for-android-phones

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modify surfaceflinger in userspace, or the kernel audio driver, or insert something in between them.

Comment: Is there any tutorial out there may shed some light on it? I'm not familiar with how android os is handling audio

Comment: If you want to do this project, you are going to need to learn a lot about how it works.  The surfaceflinger code is available to examine.